# How do I return a regex match that can be iterated repeatedly

Tags: regex, scala, iterator, set-comprehension

I can only seem to iterate over the result val once. Calling length iterates over it, and therefore calling `result.next` causes an exception.

```
    val result = for ( regex(name) <- regex findAllIn output) yield name
    println(result.length)
    println(result.next)
```

The result is AFAIK an Iterator[String], so I'm not sure why I can only iterate on it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try calling something like `toVector` on it so it stores it in a persistent collection, then you can iterate over it as many times as you like.

`Iterator` will only let you traverse over the contents once, hence if you want to traverse it more than one time then turn it into a collection. Given that you have an `Iterator[String]`, calling something like `.toVector` on it will give you a `Vector[String]`.

Answer (score 2):

> The result is AFAIK an Iterator[String], so I'm not sure why I can only iterate on it once.

Because this is how `Iterator`s work. You can't walk back or reset them - once you have iterated through them, they are "used up".

A workaround is to convert the result into e.g. a `List`, which has no such limitations:

```
val result = (for ( regex(name) <- regex findAllIn output) yield name).toList
println(result.length)
println(result.head)
```